# Tools available for creating a BPMN file

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bpmn.io

Does anyone know if there is a free online tool available to create BPMN files except bpmn.io?

I have been using BPMN io for a while, and it does not allow me to change the task/event's ID from the GUI. Because of this, I have to do this manually. But it's not practical when there is a large number of events/tasks. Can someone tell me if there is a free online alternative for bpmn.io that can change the event's ID or if there is a way to change the id in bpmn.io? Did a background check on this and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the offering from Camunda - [Camunda Web Modeler (CaWeMo)](https://cawemo.com).  I don't think it does what you are asking though.  I didn't think event IDs were part of the BPMN specification, since they are likely more about implementation than modeling, but I've not actually looked into the BPMN specification that deeply.

If the one you are using exports in a format that you find useful, you could update the event nodes as a post processing step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using https://kiegroup.github.io/kogito-online/#/editor/bpmn for bpmn authoring.